# Uploading asp.net core 2.1 site to 1&1 shared hosting (windows hosting)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.1

I have recently been playing around with asp.net core. I have built a site and have uploaded all the project files to my hosting account via FTP using FileZilla. When I then try to access the site I get a 403.14

I deleted the files from the server and tried to FTP it from visual studio and absolutely nothing happened. No files were uploaded.

In the end, I went back to FileZilla and re-uploaded the files but I am back to my original 403.14 error.

I probably should have said in the beginning that the site works fine when I run it on my local machine when I debug in visual studio.

Have I missed some step that I was previously unaware of? Am I being a dummy? I just don't seem to know what I am doing lol.

I have never done this before, I was up until a couple of weeks ago a webforms guy. Sadly webforms seems to be getting killed off by Microsoft, so adapt or die as they say. Sadly at this moment in time, I don't seem to be adapting all that well.

Comment: Does your web hosting service support Asp.Net Core?

Comment: According to their website they do.

Comment: You may be more familiar with interpreted languages like PHP, where you just load up something like `index.php` in the browser and you get your site. That's not how ASP.NET Core  works. It is compiled and needs to be explicitly started (i.e. run) before it can start answering requests. You'll need to check with your hosting provider, but if they support ASP.NET Core, then there will be some way to get a service of some sort to run your app.

Comment: Thank you both. I have figured out what I was doing wrong. I needed to deploy locally then upload those files to the server. Now it works. Thanks again.

Comment: @M_Griffiths can you explain how you did it step by step? I am having some problems too.